# Rename the files' names

Tags: python, filenames

I'd like to change the files whose extension are '.test.txt' into '.txt'.
As my codes as below, it cannot work cause invalid syntax happened to the place of 'if'.
Could you please figure out it?
Thank you so much.

```
import sys
import os

path = "Dir"
for(dirpath,dirnames,files)in os.walk(path):
   for filename in files:
           filepath = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
    if '.test.txt' in filename:
           newfilename = filename.replace('.test.txt','.txt')
           os.rename(filename,newfilename)
```

Comment: Your indentation is off at that point ...

Comment: Does this indentation match your original one? Your `if` should be indented under the `filepath = ...` line

Comment: you can do this with `ren *.test.txt *.txt` at least in windows (there is probably a simple equivalent for the other OS's

Answer (score 1):

this should work...

```
import sys
import os

path = r"Dir"
for dirpath,dirnames,files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
        if '.test.txt' in filename:
            newfilename = filename.replace('.test.txt','.txt')
            newfilepath = os.path.join(dirpath, newfilename)
            os.rename(filepath, newfilepath)
```

you did not define the new file path, in renaming action you have to supply the full file path, `os.rename(src_path, dest_path)`